# FB.ui dialog (iframe) is invisible

Tags: facebook, dialog, fb.ui

i am trying to add the stream.publish functionality to my web app, but i'm having a problem with the 'feed' dialog.

My code is the following:

```
        var obj = {
            method: 'feed',
            display: 'iframe',
            name: data.name,
            link: data.link,
            picture: data.picture,
            caption: data.name,
            description: data.description,
            message: data.message,
            actions: [{
                name: data.actions.name,
                link: data.actions.link
            }],
            user_message_prompt: ''
        }

        var resp = FB.ui(obj, function(response) {
            alert("DONE");
        });
```

I can make it work if i use 'popup' instead of 'iframe' but that's not what i want.

Any ideas why the feed is just not appearing in my screen???

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you use this code? Canvas Application, Site, Page Tab?

Answer (score 1):

As described in [Dialogs documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/)

> If you specify `iframe`, you must have a valid `access_token`. To get a valid `access_token`, please see the [Authentication guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

**Update:**
Seems there is couple of other statements that may lead to this behaviour:

> `iframe`: Display the dialog in a lightbox iframe on the current page. Because of the risk of clickjacking, this is only allowed for some certain dialogs, and requires you to pass a valid `access_token`.

And this one.

> On Facebook canvas pages, Dialogs are supported only for iframe applications

There is also open [BUG #246637628719849](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/246637628719849) about "Send Dialog" not working with as `iframe` in Page Tabs (which may, or may not be related).

**Update2:**
Actually in all my applications I've user `FB.ui` without specifying `display` since at the time of implementation of Dialogs `iframe` wasn't working well in most cases, and without it Facebook JS-SDK trying to use most appropriate display mode...

**Update3:**
OP had `fb-root` within other DOM element which was hidden, causing Dialog to be invisible (as he stated in comment)

Comment: I have a valid access_token, if i also add it in the obj object nothing happens. Any other ideas?

Comment: Actually i had the fb-root div inside another div with display:none added so the iframe was hidden behind it :$

Comment: @AlbertoSheinfeld, I've updated my answer with info from your comment. Don't accept it, we just leave it as a reminder...

Comment: Hello. Do you think you can comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584358/fb-ui-in-an-iframe-what-is-the-method-to-do-this? How do I set the parent -- is it always fb-root? Do I need to get an access token? And if I do, more problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594189/facebook-graph-api-getting-an-access-token-with-an-app-id-and-secret