# Facebook Graph API: getting an access token with an app ID and secret

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/:

Here is what I put in my browser:

> https://graph.facebook.com/?endpoint&key=value&access_token=[THE APP ID]|[THE APP SECRET]

Here is the result.. an error message:

> (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: endpoint

Help!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question is not clear at all!

Comment: I need an access token.. in case there's more than one, I need an access token to allow me to generate a "feed" in an iframe instead of as a popup. (By the way, interesting trick with the ">".)

Comment: Well, you already posted the link to the Facebook docs... So why don't you implement the OAuth process as it's described?

Comment: Tobi: because I get an error... and/or I don't grok it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Goes to "https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer"
2. Copy the code of "Access Token"

I use "Access Token" as Token for Rfacebook Packages. and it works.

Hope it can work on your side.

Answer (score 1):

The error told everything : endpoint alias does not exist.

If you want to generate the Facebook access token to test, just use the Graph API Explorer:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
```

Or, you should use Oauth process to grant the Facebook app to get access_token.

Comment: I guess I'm not very sure about how to structure the query request. I took that URL literally. Someone really needs to rewrite those docs..